# Magento 2.3.6 - Stock do not go from 1 to 0

Tags: module, stock, magento2.3.6

We have Magento 2.3.6 and MIS is disabled.

So we have an issue when products are sold from any number down to 0 it does not decrease at all.

E.g. if we have 10 left of a product and someone buys 10 the products still stay at 10. Then we have another customer that buys the same products but we do not have any left. Then we need to cancel the order. If we cancel the order the stock goes from 10 to 11...

Do anyone else have this issue and have a fix? For some reason, I can't enable the MIS module for some reason.

Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was related to a 3rd party payment.

We used Dibs Easycheckout and they released a fix that solved the issue.